# Lodash: filter when I have nested array property?

Tags: lodash

Consider below example. I am using Lodash

```
"home":[
   {
      "data":{
         "interests":["sports", "travel", "boxing"],
         "city":["x", "y", "z"],
         "name":"test1"
      },
      "count":["1", "2"],
      "country":"CA"
   },
   {
      "data":{
         "interests":["painting", "travel", "dancing"],
         "city":["a", "y", "b"],
         "name":"test2"
      },
      "count":["1","3"],
      "country":"US"
   }
]
```

If I'll try the function on key value pair example :

```
_.find(home, ['data.country', 'US']);  // It is returning me the 2nd object
```

requirement :

I want all the objects where data.interests is 'dancing'.

Tried :

```
_.find(home, ['data.interests', 'dancing'])  // It is returning []
```

I have also tried filter(), where() and map but unable to get the complete object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vanilla JS or lodash funcntions -  Filter the array, and for each item check if the `data.interests` array includes the requested word.

Vanilla:

```js
const home = [{"data":{"interests":["sports","travel","boxing"],"city":["x","y","z"],"name":"test1"},"count":["1","2"],"country":"CA"},{"data":{"interests":["painting","travel","dancing"],"city":["a","y","b"],"name":"test2"},"count":["1","3"],"country":"US"}]

const result = home.filter(o => o.data.interests.includes('dancing'))

console.log(result)
```

Lodash:

```js
const home = [{"data":{"interests":["sports","travel","boxing"],"city":["x","y","z"],"name":"test1"},"count":["1","2"],"country":"CA"},{"data":{"interests":["painting","travel","dancing"],"city":["a","y","b"],"name":"test2"},"count":["1","3"],"country":"US"}]

const result = _.filter(home, o => _.includes(o.data.interests, 'dancing'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```